# Limited Grant Permissions On Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

How does one create a privileged user in MySQL( not root ) for the sole purpose of creating other users?

However, this user can only grant access to one database at a time.

Is it possible to give limited GRANT permissions to a user?

Comment: Damn, I would've loved to have seen this answered. Since it's been over a year now, have you found out anything by yourself?

Answer (score -1):

```
    yes you can create mysql user and  grant limited permissions using phpmyadmin    
     interface and also by command 
    use following command for creating user and grant permissions



        CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';

      GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

you can further explore on

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Creating users is not the  problem. I want to limit the GRANT permissions available to a user to only ONE database at a time